# Jhipster disable RememberMe auth

Tags: jhipster

How can we remove the rememberme part from files generated with jhipster ? Do you have some documentation about this part ? I looked into code but it doesn't seem to be done easily, or on wihch template should I see ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing the RememberMe configuration in SecurityConfiguration.java (See commented out code below), and then removed the RememberMe section from login.html? For example:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
    // .and()
    //    .rememberMe()
    //    .rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices)
    //    .key(env.getProperty("jhipster.security.rememberme.key"))
    .and()
        .formLogin() here
```

Comment: Thanks, Yes I already did that (it was needed for the CAS authentication that I added), but i would clean the project without all this feature. I removed also some parts on the dababase about the Persistent_token, but is it rigth ? and what can I remove on Angualr side ?